# jqgrid not working with viewmodel but worked with model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, viewmodel, jqgrid-asp.net

I am trying to modify and existing jqGrid which was displaying data till now via a model in C# MVC, but instead of just displaying data from just one model i have to retrieve and display data from more than one model, so i used a view model instead of a model,but data is not getting populated.

**Before:**
createReferralGrid = function (parentRowId, **referrals**, studentId, testDate) {

```
    $grid.jqGrid({
        sg_blankRowOnAdd: !_readOnly,
        sg_blankRowData: blankRow,
        cmTemplate: { sortable: false, title: false, fixed: true },
        data: referrals,............
         colModel: [
            {
                name: 'ReferralCode',
                index: 'ReferralCode',
                width: 105,
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
```

**After:**
 createReferralGrid = function (parentRowId, **rowData**, studentId, testDate) {

```
    $grid.jqGrid({
        sg_blankRowOnAdd: !_readOnly,
        sg_blankRowData: blankRow,
        cmTemplate: { sortable: false, title: false, fixed: true },
        data: rowData,
        datatype: "local",
        height: "auto",....  


        colModel: [
            {
                name: 'Referrals.ReferralCode',
                index: 'Referrals.ReferralCode',
                width: 105,
                formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
```

Note: Referrals is a model inside rowData, Earlier i was passing only referrals so the was working but now i passed the viewmodel(rowData) and i used rowData.ReferralCode in the colModel then its not working

Answer (score 0):

can you show your view model code. the problem may is of making [relation](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/one-to-one-conventions-entity-framework-core.aspx) with the models correctly
you need to know

One to One relations

One to many

many to many relation

may this was help full for you

Comment: public class StudentExamGridViewModel
    {
        public BaseStudentMedicalExamModel Exam { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public List<Referral> Referrals { get; set; }
        public List<ReferralStateCommon> ReferralStateCommons { get; set; }
*******************************************



                     https://hmp.me/cadr
**********************************
                  I am getting data in the jquery but not able to display via jqgrid. Added screenshot from debug mode

Answer (score 0):

After alot of search i found that we cannot access view models in jqgrid, we need to pass a model only to jqgrid or some other data source which has direct values inside it not in nested format.